# Separate data items by row

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have total 4 items form database using Laravel, i want to separate it so 
     there will be 2 items per row, means 2 at the top and 2 at the bottom

This is my code:

```html
@extends('layouts/app') 
@section('content')
    <h1>Clubs & Societies</h1>
    <p>This is Clubs And Societies</p>
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    @if (count($categories)>0)
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <div class="container col-md-3">
                <div class="card card-body bg-light row-fluid" style="display:flex">
                    {{$category->category_name}}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach

    @else
        <p>No Category Found</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your `$categories` into collections with 02 items per collection, using chunk() method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk

```
$categories = $categories->chunk(2);
```

Now you can iterate through `$categories->first()`, at the top, and `$categories->last()`, at the bottom.